# Error: initial value of reference to non-const must be an value

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, operators

```
class A
{

public:

    int v;
    A * p;
    A& operator*(const A& a)
    {
        return this->v*a.v// here is a red line under this say error initial value of reference to non-const must be an value
    }
    ~A()
    {
        this;
    }
};

int main()
{
    A a;
    a.p = new A;
    delete a.p;
    return 0;

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

overloading * operator I cannot use this to represent the object itself. Why this happened.

Comment: It is a binary operator (multiply) - not a pointer dereference.

Comment: Oh. yes. you are right.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Surely it says that it must be an *lvalue*.  You're trying to return a reference to a temporary.  This is bad karma.

Besides, it's not at all what you want.  The multiplication operator should definitely return a value, not a reference.

Not sure what your constructor looks like, but assuming it takes an integer:

```
A operator * (A const& other) const
{
    return A{ v * other.v};
};
```

Edit:

And actually you should go a step further:

```
struct A
{
    A& operator *= (A const& other) { v *= other.v; return *this; }
    A(int i) : v(i) {}
private:
    int v;
}

A operator * (A lh, A const& rh)
{
   A res{std::move(lh)};
   res *= rh;
   return res;
}
```

Comment: Or just `return lh *= rh;`. No `std::move` or yet another local variable needed.

Comment: Did you forget a `return *this;` in `operator*=`?

Comment: @zenith - doesn't so much matter in this case, but the temporary actually serves an important purpose when the objects are larger.  It allows the compiler to perform parameter passing and return value optimizations.  If you return the value parameter directly that can't happen.  See 'Want speed? Pass by value'.  Hard to find now that Abrahams' page is gone, but it's still out there.

Comment: https://web.archive.org/web/20140205194657/http://cpp-next.com/archive/2009/08/want-speed-pass-by-value/

Answer (score 3):

`this->v*a.v` evaluates to an `int`. An `int` cannot be converted to an `A&`.

Use

```
A operator*(const A& a) // Return a value, not a reference.
{
   A res;
   res.v = this->v*a.v;
   return res;
}
```

You should make the member function a `const` member function too since it does not modify the object.

```
A operator*(const A& a) const
{
   A res;
   res.v = this->v*a.v;
   return res;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The result of `this->v * a.v` is an **rvalue**, a temporary unnamed value. As a temporary, it cannot bind to a *non-const* reference. Only **lvalues** can bind to *non-const* references. That's what the error "initial value of reference to non-const must be an **l**value" is referring to.

However, you don't want to return a const reference either, you want to return the value by value:

```
A operator*(const A& a) { … }
 ^ remove &
```

Note: this will not fix your code completely as you're trying to return an `int` where you declared to return an `A`, and `int` isn't implicitly convertible to `A` in your current code.