# invalid initialization of non-const reference of type cost char*& from a temporary of type const char*

Tags: c++, reference

After compiling the following program i get this error:

```
char const* func(char const* a, char const* b)
{
        return std::strcmp(a,b)<0?b:a;
}

char const*& func(char const*& a, char const*& b,char const*& c)
{
        return func(func(a,b),c);
}
int main()
{
    const char* a="First";
    const char* b="Second";
    const char* c="Third";

    func(func(a,b),c); //ERROR
    return 0;
}
```

**Questions:**

**1.** The error is thrown because of func(a,b) return value but i dont know the reason for it.

**2.** Why is the temporary created while returning from the func(char const*,char const*)? IS it created because caller side doesnt have a variable to collect the returned value?

**EDIT : This Error has been discussed in other threads but the scenario is different(though the reason hopefully has to be the same) in this case hence i have asked this question because the explanation is not evident in this scenario. Please dont mark it as duplicate.**

Comment: You are creating a temporary copy of the pointer and assigning it to a referenced value. That would become invalid when the temporary object is out of scope.

Comment: @JHBonarius: Greetings! Could you explain the "*creating a temporary copy of the pointer and assigning it to a referenced value.*" in more detail. Is the temporary created because the caller side has nothing to collect in?   Also when you say _assigning it to a reference value_  which referenced value are we talking about?

Comment: Because you've reused names it's very hard to reference to specific parts of your code. Please don't do that in the future. When the first call to func returns, it's return value -a temporary- is passed to the second call of func by reference. You then try to seems this back to the main local variable by reference again.

Comment: Pointers are just values. Your first function makes local copies of those values, while the second uses reference addresses to the original memory location of the values.

Comment: Why not answer it so that i can accept

Comment: Your question is closed. It is impossible to answer anymore.

Comment: Yeah i didnt realize. It is becoming increasingly hard to use SO day by day due to these self proclaimed superiors

Comment: @JHBonarius you can answer now. It was a nice few months with that guy banned where he couldn't close every single question as duplicate of some unrelated question with 1 or 2 words in common

Comment: Also seems to be a swarm of downvoting robots for both questions and answers.  Sigh.  SO should just remove downvoting, or mandate downvoting with reason and allow the downvote to be downvoted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I misjudged your question at first, because I misread your code. Actually, in your code `char const*& func(char const*& a, char const*& b,char const*& c)` is never called ;)

This part of your code actually works correctly:

```
#include<cstring>
char const* func(char const* a, char const* b)
{
    return std::strcmp(a, b)<0 ? b : a;
}

#include<iostream>
int main()
{
    const char* a = "First";
    const char* b = "Second";
    const char* c = "Third";

    std::cout << func(func(a, b), c) << std::endl;
    std::cin.ignore();
    return 0;
}
```

which returns "third"

The problem is created when you change `func(func(a, b), c)` in main into `func(a, b, c)`. This is because you are combining pointers with references to pointers. This is possible to do, but not the way you do it.

Now if you call `func(a, b, c)`, all the arguments are passed to the second function *by reference*. To demonstrate what that means, consider this code:

```
#include<iostream>
int main()
{
    const char* a = "First";
    std::cout << "a: " << (void*)a << ", &a:" << &a << std::endl;
    const char* b = "Second";
    std::cout << "b: " << (void*)b << ", &b:" << &b << std::endl;
    const char* c = "Third";
    std::cout << "c: " << (void*)c << ", &c:" << &c << std::endl;

    std::cin.ignore();
    return 0;
}
```

For me this returns:

```
a: 00938B30, &a:00B9FEEC
b: 00938BE4, &b:00B9FEE0
c: 00938BF4, &c:00B9FED4
```

See? `a` is a pointer which contains an address, *but there is also an address that points to `a`!*. These are passed when you call by reference.

However, within this (second `func`) function, you call the first `func` which **copies** the pointer values, as it is not passing arguments by reference. These *local copies* are temporary values, that are destroyed once the functions goes out of scope. The problem occurs are the second (`func`) function tries to write the address of this local copy to the value called by reference.

OK, I don't know if you're following me here. Let's demonstrate what's happening in memory by an example:

```
#include<cstring>
#include<iostream>

char const* func(char const* const a, char const* const b)
{
    std::cout << "Func1:\n";
    std::cout << "local: a: " << (void*)a << "<--copy, &a:" << &a << "<--*different from main!*\n";
    std::cout << "local: b: " << (void*)b << "<--copy, &b:" << &b << "<--*different from main!*\n";
    return std::strcmp(a, b)<0 ? b : a;
}

char const*& func(char const*& a, char const*& b, char const*& c)
{
    std::cout << "Func2:\n";
    std::cout << "ref: a: " << (void*)a << "<--original, &a:" << &a << "<--original\n";
    std::cout << "ref: b: " << (void*)b << "<--original, &b:" << &b << "<--original\n";
    std::cout << "ref: c: " << (void*)c << "<--original, &c:" << &c << "<--original\n";
    char const* const out = func(func(a, b), c);
    std::cout << "Func2:\n";
    std::cout << "local: out: " << (void*)out << ", &out:" << &out << " (cannot return this local variable to a reference)\n";
    return c; // just to fix it for now
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Main:\n";
    const char* a = "First";
    std::cout << "a: " << (void*)a << ", &a:" << &a << "\n";
    const char* b = "Second";
    std::cout << "b: " << (void*)b << ", &b:" << &b << "\n";
    const char* c = "Third";
    std::cout << "c: " << (void*)c << ", &c:" << &c << "\n";

    func(a, b, c);
    std::cin.ignore();
    return 0;
}
```

For me this returns:

```
Main:
a: 00F38D00, &a:005EF78C
b: 00F38C00, &b:005EF780
c: 00F38D08, &c:005EF774
Func2:
ref: a: 00F38D00<--original, &a:005EF78C<--original
ref: b: 00F38C00<--original, &b:005EF780<--original
ref: c: 00F38D08<--original, &c:005EF774<--original
Func1:
local: a: 00F38D00<--copy, &a:005EF5A4<--*different from main!*
local: b: 00F38C00<--copy, &b:005EF5A8<--*different from main!*
Func1:
local: a: 00F38C00<--copy, &a:005EF5A8<--*different from main!*
local: b: 00F38D08<--copy, &b:005EF5AC<--*different from main!*
Func2:
local: out: 00F38D08, &out:005EF680 (cannot return this local variable to a reference)
```

[live demo](http://rextester.com/ZVYY28458)

I hope this is clear enough for you

Comment: I didn't follow your answer completely but i got the gist of it. If i understand you(the gist) correctly from your answer, the issue occurs precisely during the return of func(func(a,b,,c) to main because while returning it tries to get a reference to a temporary which is not allowed.

Comment: A short example would prove this:

`char *& func(char * a, char * b)
{
        return func1(a,b);
}

int main()
{
        char* a="First";
        char* b="Second";
        char* c="Third";

        func(a,b);
}`
//This simply means that the return from func1 returns a temporary char* which is returned from func as reference to pointer to temporary and as the rule of c++ says referencing to temporary is not allowed.

Comment: @anurag86 in the end you want to return by reference in the second function. However, by using the first function you lose the ability to do so. To fix it, you either need both functions to have the same signature. Either both reference or not.

Comment: @anurag86 By the way MSVS2017 shows the warning: ["initial value of reference to non-const must be an lvalue"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33001702/error-initial-value-of-reference-to-non-const-must-be-an-value) and when compiling ["error C2440: 'return': cannot convert from 'const char *' to 'const char *&'"](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sy5tsf8z.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Comment: True. I think MSVS2017 gives more intuitive message.